# Background Operation when the app is running

Tags: android, web-services, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I was wondering if it is possible ( it should actually) to run a piece of code every couple of minutes even if the user is using the app. The basic Idea behind this is that the User will take the smart phone with my app loaded in the field and start collecting data, while he is collecting data or playing with other options of the app the phone catches the 3g/wifi zone it will start syncing the data to the server. I keep pushing notifications to the devices from my web service using Google Cloud messaging (GCM) and when it reaches the phone it means the phone is now connected to the internet I run that piece of code which do the sync for me. Would it stop the current activity of the app or I would say do the user will be able to keep collecting data and the sync is also running on the background?. any idea of this type of scenario?

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that communicates with a server is by nature asynchronous in ActionScript (and you can't make it synchronous). So just do what you'd normally do to communicate with the server. Other processing, such as loops over a large collection or drawing a lot of objects, [can make the application unresponsive](http://www.craftymind.com/tag/elastic-racetrack/).

Comment: so, I will  be selecting records from SQLite inside device and posting them to the web server. what happens to the loop which is selecting the records from device? is it gonna be stopping the user activities in the phone or it is gonna be in the background?

Comment: my loops are not so large so jsut want to keep them in background and the app user do his job without knowing it is syncing too.

Comment: I can't imagine you have millions of records or complicated joins on the phone that would result in a dramatic slowdown.

Comment: guys, Now it is getting out of control, I have have got 1 web service with 12 method in it, I have a SQLite table with 12 tables, I get records from the server table via the web service and insert them in to  the sqlite table. I used loop and stuff for looping though services, doing inserts and stuff. when I start the sync my application freezes until it finishes, I cant do anything while this process.

Comment: Send a batch of records up to the server and allow the server to process it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). And your application will not stop while AsyncTask is running in background.

Comment: I saw some posts telling that it is not available in flash builder! I used flash builder 4.7 is it something that I can implement in flash builder too? thanks for the reply

Comment: I am not sure about that as i have not used it but you can use AsyncTask for your webservice to run in background

Comment: well I need to use AsyncTask in my mobile app not the web service. since the data is stored in a sqlite database inside the device and when the device is connected to the internet it start pushing the data out to the webservice.